# How to anchor with javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web system in java, jsp.

I have at **the end of my home page a contact form** where I need to validate ...

I made some (Ex: name can not be null) in javascript ... but I would also like to do the backend (servlet).

I'm using a button submit and sending the information to the servlet ...

Assuming that in servlet validation the name is null, I feed a list of errors and show it just below the contact form.

```
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope.erros}">

    <div class="erro">
        <c:forEach var="erro" items="${requestScope.erros}">
            <li><c:out value="${erro}"/></li>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>

</c:if>
```

The problem is that the form is at the bottom of the page, so for the user to know that there was an error he would have to scroll to the end to check.

Is there any way to make a kind of "anchor javascript"?When page loads if errors! = Null scroll page to contact div.

Comment: can you use jquery as well ?

Comment: @Swati I know that with jquery would work, because I would not need reload ... but no, I can not use jqery for particular reasons. I need to submit.

Comment: No , i mean to say for scroll can you use jquery ,if yes you can write like this . i.e : whenever your page get reload you can check `if($(".erro").length > 0){$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.erro').offset().top
    }, 'slow');}`   put these lines under `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Comment: @Swati Yes, you can use it. I don't understand your code well ... "error" is a session attribute and the form class id is "contact". How would the code look?

Comment: @Swati It worked. Would you like to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                    var erros = document.getElementById("erro");
                    if (erros != null) {
                        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#contato").offset().top
                        }, 2000);
                    }


                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is,

if there are errors you can insert this script :

```
<script>
   var elmnt = document.getElementById("idOfErrorDiv");
   elmnt.scrollIntoView();
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this way ... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null"...and the id is correct, i have html anchors pointing to it.

Comment: Add `id="errors"` to your `<div>`, and then use `getElementById("errors")`.